# How I can customize my tabbed page in master detail page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, tabbedpage

I have been struggled with customizing a tabbed page for long time.

I need to move the hamburger menu icon to next by tab menu and disable the title name of tabbed page ("Home") (In iOS, bottom tabbed to top tabbed)

I guess I should use some custom renderer, but I couldn't find website and documents dealing with my case.

Please check it out and Help me. :blush:

My pages hierarchy:
    Master/DetailPage -> NavigationPage(in Detail) -> Tabbed Page -> Content Page

[As Is Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXPXi.jpg)
[To Do Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8C1z.png)

Answer (score 0):

If just want to remove the title in Android,Maybe the way can help you:
In **AndroidManifest.xml** file,add the **theme** property

```
<application android:label="xxxxx" 
             android:theme="@style/NoTitle"/>
</application>
```

And in *Resources/values/styles.xml* add the **NoTitle** style

```
<style name="NoTitle">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**Also**, the same other way you also can try,in *Resources/values/styles.xml* find taht

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
```

and add this item,

```
 <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
```

In native android,this way can work.Hope this way can help you.